# Link my php search results to another page

Tags: php, html

I am beginner in `php`, i have coded a search result function that is clickable . My problem is how to click a specific search item that can be clicked and open in another page by full details. Below my code for the `searresults.php` page or the target page after a client click one search item:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<!DOCTYPE  HTML> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Search Results</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <h3>Search Results</h3> 

    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","1");
        $excursion_id = $_GET['excursion_id'];
        $sql = "select * from excursionitem where excursion_id = '$excursion_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        { 
            $Item_Name = $row['Item_Name'];
            $Description = $row['Description'];
            $Price = $row['Price'];
            $excursion_id = $row['excursion_id'];

            echo '$excursion_id' ;
        }
    ?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Any help from your side will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Apart from that, I don't seem to clearly understand what you mean by _"how to click a specific search item that can be clicked and open in another page by full details"_. Can you explain better?

Comment: i mean when a client search my (excursion) data base a result will appear in brief ..but when he click in one item (for example) he should be redirected to anothrr page carrying all this item full details

Comment: Don't try to run before learning to walk. You're welcome -> https://www.udemy.com/phpmysql-for-beginners/

Comment: you are right...but i am working hard to accomplish my project

Answer (score 0):

If you want only list `hyperlink` clickable, and redirect to other page.

Try it:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    $Item_Name = $row['Item_Name'];
    $Description = $row['Description'];
    $Price = $row['Price'];
    $excursion_id = $row['excursion_id'];
?>

    <a href="OTHERPAGE.php?id=<?=$excursion_id?>">More datails</a><br />

<?php
}
```

Is it?